# How to grant selection rights for a specific table in a SQL database

Tags: sql, mariadb

I would like to grant selection rights for a specific table in a database in SQL. I know how to grant the rights for all tables in the database:

```
GRANT SELECT ON  `web01\_database\_home`.* TO `user-1_ert`@`%` ;
```

The database `web01\_database\_home` has a table called `test_table_1`, so I tried to replace the `*` with that table name:

```
GRANT SELECT ON  `web01\_database\_home`.test_table_1 TO `user-1_ert`@`%` ;
GRANT SELECT ON  `web01\_database\_home.test_table_1` TO `user-1_ert`@`%` ;
```

Neither of those worked. How can I do this?

Comment: It would **really** help if you would share the text of the error message. And where did you get "grand" from "grant"? Once is a typo, but three separate times? When the correct word is right there in the SQL?

Comment: Thanks Joel for your comment. First of all I have to say that this is not a MySQL database. So your edit is not correct. About the error messages: When using the first command, I get the error message `"SELECT, GRANT command denied to user '`user-1_ert'@'2a00:1398:5:800:7934:22e:9b8f:1b0d' for table 'test_table_1' */"` and for the second command `"Table 'web01\_database\_home.test_table_1' doesn't exist */"`

Comment: MySql and MariaDB are the only databases that use backticks as separators, and MariaDB is much less common here recently. If you don't tag the database yourself, you're gonna end up with this kind of thing. Play silly games, win silly prizes. Also... you can still edit your own question to fix this, which you should do to include the text of the error.

Comment: @JoelCoehoorn: Thanks for your comment. What do you mean by "If you don't tag the database yourself, you're gonna end up with this kind of thing. "? How can I tag the database myself and what kind of "thing" are you referring to?

Comment: Click the edit button on the question. You'll see a place to change what tags you use.

Answer (score 0):

Ahh, I see it says MariaDB - I just looked that up and found there was a manual (the GRANT section: https://mariadb.com/kb/en/grant/#grant-option)
that contains this line, regarding giving permissions to specific columns of a table:

```
GRANT SELECT (name, position) on Employee to 'jeffrey'@'localhost';
```

Strangely, it doesn't seem to specify how to do it for a full table, but perhaps replacing (name, permission) with * might do it?

Just spitballing, but good luck

Answer (score -1):

I believe if you add OBJECT:: it may work for you:

```
GRANT SELECT ON OBJECT::test_table_1 TO user-1_ert;
```

Source: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/grant-object-permissions-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver16

Comment: Thanks for your answer Kevin. Unfortunately I get an error when using your suggested code `You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near '::test_table_1 `web01\_database\_home`.* TO `user-1_ert`@`%`' at line 1 */`

Comment: this is for ms sql and not mysql